# How to Prevent Cursor Jump in a Text Element When Using Negative Margin-Left Properties

Tags: html, oracle-apex

Need to move a text element left. When clicking in a text element, after using negative `margin-left` properties, the cursor is jumping to the beginning of the text. When margin-left properties are removed then the cursor stays in the location that was clicked.

I tried using the negative `left` property. This does not yield a result. 
I am not seeing anyone else encounter this on google. 
Is there another way to move an element left in Oracle Apex?

```
<textarea name="p_t29" class="textarea" id="P76_SECTOR3_INFO" style="width: 479px; height: 145px; margin-top: -140px; margin-left: -1171px;" maxlength="4000" rows="5" cols="80" wrap="virtual">•
•
•
•
•
•
•
•
•</textarea>
```

Comment: Have you put `position: relative` when using `left: -140px`? Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: `position: relative` did the trick. Thank you friend. If you answer it I can award you points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added `position: [relative/absolute/fixed];` to element for any `left`/`right` and `top`/`bottom` to work.

Default element position is `position: static` and it prevents adjusting element position.